# Quick Launch Sharepoint 2007

Tags: quick-launch, 2007

I need to get all sub Sites from Sites in Quick Lanch Menu in Sharepoint 2007 programatically . Can any provide me sample code to get all second navigation links in Quick Launch. Urgent..?

Answer (score 1):

Just use the "normal" left/quick navigation.

Its driven by an SiteMapDataSource (driven by a SiteMapProvider) and an aspmenu control.

See examples on MSDN [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms466994.aspx) and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms432695.aspx)